# How to change the icon navigation drawer closed or opened

Tags: android

My question is very clear that i want to change the Up icon When  NavigationDrawer open and closed. So please tell me how to Change the upp icon in anction bar. I have tried so much but i m not able to do. ii have used custom layout to set the title. Thanks in advance

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.center_action_bar_text);
        actionBar.setTitle("dvds");
        View view = actionBar.getCustomView();
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        textView.setText("zfdgfdg");
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);


        ---------------------------------
        drawerListView.setAdapter(drawerListAdapter);
        DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);


        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(HomeActivity.this,
                drawerLayout, R.drawable.abc_ic_clear_search_api_holo_light, R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close){

                    @Override
                    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                        super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                        super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                    }
        };
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
             return true;
           }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

[image: I want to use this image when drawer open]
[image: I want to use this image when drawer closed]

Comment: Could you please be more specific? Which images would you like to set for the open and closed states? Do you still want the sliding animation as the Drawer opens and closes?

Answer (score 1):

Add this method to your code:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Comment: This will just cause the Toggle to reload the image originally set. I don't think that's what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 1):

i have other one answer

just add this method:-

```
@Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        //boolean drawerOpen1 = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(this.slider);
        //menu.findItem(R.id.sliding).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        if(drawerOpen)
        {
            menu.findItem(R.id.sliding).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel);
        }
        else {
            menu.findItem(R.id.sliding).setIcon(R.drawable.menuicon);
        }
        //menu.findItem(R.id.sliding).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        //menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen1);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

for that method call you need to use this tow method

```
invalidateOptionsMenu();
// calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
```

when menu is open

```
    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
        //mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.END);
        // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
```

when menu is close

```
public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                //menu.findItem(R.id.sliding).;
                //mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.END);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons

                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
```